# Dropdown list populated from database

Tags: asp.net

I have populated a dropdownlist from a database. Now on select of a particular item I want the data to come from the database and get displayed in a label, but, when I am selecting a particular item, the page gets loaded again and in the dropdownlist --SELECT-- comes again and not the value which I previously selected.

My code is-

aspx page-


https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

**codebehind-**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    if (Session["UI"]==null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("AdminLogin.aspx");
    }


    else
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            AddVehicle vb = new AddVehicle();
            DataSet tt = vb.populatedropdown();
            DropDownList1.DataSource = tt;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "DealerID";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "DealerID";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you arent making sense. you "select an item, page loads again" - of course. it is doing a postback. This is normal. This is what happens. In your code, the DataTextField is incorrect. This should be the actual text/column name from the DB - not the ID. But even so with this correction, you are setting the --SELECT-- option somewhere as if it postsback then the value you chose would remain unaffected unless your code does something somewhere else to affect it

Comment: aspx code is-<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem Text="--SELECT--" Value="0" ></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: DataTextField is correct,it is the exact column name from database

Comment: OK - here is a test. Remove the ListItem you have defined and add the code after you databind instead i.e DropDownList1.Items.Add(....) for your SELECT item

Comment: Do you have viewstate enabled?

Comment: no,there is no view state enabled

Comment: @user3054094 Ok after postback is your dropdownlist is empty? Show us your selectedindexchanged event.

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Session["UI"] == null)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("AdminLogin.aspx");
                }
                        
                AddVehicle vb = new AddVehicle();
                DataSet tt = vb.populatedropdown();
                DropDownList1.DataSource = tt;
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "DealerID";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "DealerID";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();

Comment: protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dealerid = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            AddVehicle hj = new AddVehicle();
            string dealername1 = hj.displaytextbox(dealerid);
            TextBox1.Text = dealername1;
        }

Comment: dropdowmlist.selectedvalue is always 0,how to avoid it?